# Issues in installing packages on webfraction

Tags: python, django

I am trying to setup my project on web-fraction . My project using some external packages and when I installed them using pip they got installed in root lib dir i.e., `$HOME/bin` but my project is using  python inside my app  i.e., `$HOME/webapp/app/bin` . Now I simply wants that I can able to install packages inside my app i.e., inside webapp . I have used one command for this but that doesn't work :

```
pip-2.7 install --install-option="--install-script=$PWD/bin" --install-option="--install-lib=$PWD/lib/python2.7" package
```

I have read webfraction docs but I didn't get it right . So please tell me the steps how I can install packages inside webapp .

Answer (score 0):

For instance, let's say you want to install django-haystack 2.0.0 on webfaction, using pip. You could do the following ($PWD does not work I think) :

```
pip-2.7 install django-haystack==2.0.0 --install-option="--install-scripts=/home/your_account/webapps/your_django_app/bin" --install-option="--install-lib=/home/your_account/webapps/your_django_app/lib/python2.7"
```